# perform a redirect from module class onbootstrap method

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

Is there a proper method to perform a redirect inside the `Application Module class` using zend framework?

I'd like to reconstruct this code to use a zend based redirection.

```
class Moudle
{

      public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
      {
         $arg = 1;
         if($arg==1){
            header("Location: index.php?redirect=1");  
            exit();  
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how others do but here is an example of what I already did in a project :

```
class Module
{

  public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
  {
     $arg = 1;
     if($arg==1){
        $response = $e->getResponse();
        $response->getHeaders()->clearHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', '/index.php?redirect=1');
        $response->setStatusCode(302)->sendHeaders();
        exit();  
     }
  };
```

If you don't want to hard code the url (which is not recommended according to me), then you can use the view helper url or the controller plugin url that you get from the service manager in order to use the name of your route instead of "/index.php?redirect=1". I always prefer to avoid hard coding url in my ZF projects as we can use the name of the routes. It's up to you.